# How can I stop and restart python script from another python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to stop and rerun python script from another python script?

My idea is like this
I have two python script [**scanner.py** ,**vpnchange.py**]
Scanner.py I want this scanner to run about 500 request then **pause** and stop and restart **vpnchange.py** then continue and so on.

Comment: what starts `vpnchange.py` in the first place? If it is anything other than `scanner.py` then this becomes complicated, platform specific and messy.  If it is started by scanner.py how is it being started?

Comment: I'm thinking that I can run it from scanner.py !! Or is there any other solution?

Comment: to start a process in parallel you use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) which for another python script might look like `vpn_script = Popen(["python3", "vpnchange.py"])` and to terminate it you call [`vpn_script.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) on the object returned by `Popen`